# Extract word in array by index into new column Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with stemmed words, tokens and non-stemmed tokens:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [{'stem_word': ['cat', 'run','today'], 'stem_tokens':  ['cat', 'run', 'today', 'in', 'the' ,'morning', 'very', 'quick'], 'tokens': ['cat', 'running', 'today', 'in' ,'the', 'morning', 'very', 'quickly']}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
+-----------------+------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------+
|stem_word        |stem_tokens                                     |tokens                                                |
+-----------------+------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------+
|[cat, run, today]|[cat, run, today, in, the, morning, very, quick]|[cat, running, today, in, the, morning, very, quickly]|
+-----------------+------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------+
```

First, I want to find indexes of words column `stem_word` in column `stem_tokens`. The indices for the `stem_tokens` column that have the words `stem_word` will be 0,1,2, so I have an array of indices:

```
list_index = [0,1,2]
```

Second, using this list of indexes, get the values from the `tokens` column ( so it will be: cat-0, running-1, today-2). This will create a `new` column:

```
+-----------------+------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+
|stem_word        |stem_tokens                                     |tokens                                                |new                  |
+-----------------+------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+
|[cat, run, today]|[cat, run, today, in, the, morning, very, quick]|[cat, running, today, in, the, morning, very, quickly]|[cat, running, today]|
+-----------------+------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+
```

These actions are necessary in order for me to turn stemmed words into non-stemmed ones.

Comment: So you want to find the indexes of the words from `stem_word` in the `stem_tokens` list?

Comment: Yes, and use these indices to find words from ` tokens`

Answer (score 0):

The logic is not fully clear, but assuming you want to subselect the lists you could use a mapping dictionary (column name -> list index):

```
list_index = [0,1,2]

d = dict(zip(df, list_index))
# {'stem_word': 0, 'stem_tokens': 1, 'tokens': 2}

out = df.apply(lambda c: c.str[d[c.name]])

print(out)
```

output:

```
  stem_word stem_tokens tokens
0       cat         run  today
```

As a new column:

```
df['new'] = out.to_numpy().tolist()
```

output:

```
           stem_word                                       stem_tokens                                                  tokens                new
0  [cat, run, today]  [cat, run, today, in, the, morning, very, quick]  [cat, running, today, in, the, morning, very, quickly]  [cat, run, today]
```

Comment: In the new column, I would like to get the words that from the tokens column that have these indices